# Rate of gain or loss - gamma distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions

Forgive me, I am pretty much going back to high school level statistics.

I have a set of data for the rate of gain or loss of a certain unit, per second.  I have put it into bins of 0.001 width. The bins range in frequency by a large amount: -0.0305 and lower bins have at most 10 occurences, whereas 0.0055 through 0.0095 have 10,000 each.

Mean    0.01067150315

Median  0.007942643757

Is a gamma distribution the best distribution to work with here? If so, how would I calculate the scale factor?

[image]

EDIT:
In my specific example, players in a game can lose or gain territory, but the size of the overall world is not zero-sum since the game will continuously generate more land. Since the territories are flexible in size, and players may join at a different time one way to show how good a player is might be to look at the rate of gain or loss of territory per second of game time. This might be expressed as 0.01 sqm/sec on average, but if a player comes in to a game late and gets immediately destroyed by, say, being located next to a very dominant player, I would not want to punish them for having a one-off, very high, negative rate of gain.

In a more general (simple?) example, maybe we can consider poker players at a cash table. They may all start with \$100. Player A may leave after two hours with \$80, player B after one hour and \$120, Player C may leave after three hours with \$130. Their rate of gain per minute would be -10, +20 and +10. Over enough hands, you could rank those players in terms of an hourly wage (or rate of gain) and if a player has a particularly good game at a table, winning \$50 in 5 minutes, we can assess the likelihood that that can be repeated. Similarly, a player that busts on their first hand will have an extremely low negative rate of gain, but the chance of being dealt a hand good enough to go all in on their first hand, and losing, was quite low.

Comment: Well, a gamma distribution have zero probability for negative values ... can you please tell us what you want to do with your model, what is the goal and context of modeling?

Comment: I've updated the original question with a specific and general example of what I am trying to figure out.